# BigQuery SQL IF over repeated record

Tags: sql, if-statement, google-bigquery

Assume I have a schema like the one mentioned in BigQuery docs:

```
Last modified                 Schema                 Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration
 ----------------- ----------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------
  27 Sep 10:01:06   |- kind: string                     4            794
                    |- fullName: string (required)
                    |- age: integer
                    |- gender: string
                    +- phoneNumber: record
                    |  |- areaCode: integer
                    |  |- number: integer
                    +- children: record (repeated)
                    |  |- name: string
                    |  |- gender: string
                    |  |- age: integer
                    +- citiesLived: record (repeated)
                    |  |- place: string
                    |  +- yearsLived: integer (repeated)
```

Assume we have fullNames : John, josh, harry

citiesLived : newyork, chicago, seattle

How do I iterate over citiesLived and count by using conditionals. For example, I'd like to count how many users with fullName = John have lived in both citiesLived.place = newyork and citiesLived.place = chicago, but haven't lived in citiesLived.place = seattle.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 7):

You can use the OMIT IF keyword. (this is undocumented, I'll file a bug to make sure it gets documented)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT fullname, 
    IF (citiesLived.place == 'newyork', 1, 0) as ny,
    IF (citiesLived.place == 'chicago', 1, 0) as chi
  FROM (FLATTEN(name_table, citiesLived))
  OMIT RECORD IF citiesLived.place = 'seattle') 
WHERE fullname = 'John' 
  AND ny == 1 
  AND chi == 1
```